# How to get the response of AJAX from JQUERY

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I know this question has been asked many times but the guys who asked before me had a slightly different issue. I have a [simple page to upload photo][1]. This one is placed on my localhost. I can select file and upload image into upload folder. I can get response and using Firefox console - "Net" tab - I can see the response - which is printed as html code. I could get the DOM using JQuery $("#message").html() function. However what I wanted to try is this. Instead of printing tags or JSON structure data just send error code. echo 0; for success. Echo -1; for failure. The live code is place [here][2]. Now what I tried with php file ajax_php_file.php is this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES["file"]["type"]))
  {
  $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
  $temporary = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  $file_extension = end($temporary);
  if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") || 
       ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") ||
       ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
  ) AND 
  $_FILES["file"]["size"] < 128000 AND // 125kb files can be uploaded.
  in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    echo '-1';
  else
  {
    echo '-2';
  if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
    echo '-3';
  }
  else
  {
  $sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; // Storing source path of the file in a variable
  $targetPath = "upload/".$_FILES['file']['name']; // Target path where file is to be stored
  move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath) ; // Moving Uploaded file
    echo '0';
  }
  }
  }
  else
  {
  echo '-3';
  }
}
?>


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36183350/why-jquery-image-uploader-doesnt-upload-image
  [2]: http://kod.djpw.cz/vpvb
```

So no html is send, just a 1 or two characters. When I check Firefox console on "Net" tab I see Just JSON but nothing more. So I have two questions here. Why I see no response, why I don't se the "0" when the file has been successfully uploaded? And then - how to fix the JS code to get the number or string without using any tags. Is this possible? My goal is to start functions which will print reports "File successly loaded" if the value is "0", or some error message if the value is less then 0.

Comment: You shouldn't see JSON, there is no JSON in that data. (Well, technically a Number is a valid JSON text, but you haven't got any code to set the right content-type so the Network tab should be treating it as HTML not JSON)

Comment: I was not asking about JSON but why there is nothing visible. But maybe I was checking wrong and overlooked the single digit because now I see value "0" there in the Responses console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jQuery

```
success: function(data) {
   alert(data); 
}
```

Comment: Tried, I have successfully uploaded file but I got this message:-20. Why there is -20 and not 0?

Comment: May be because you don't have the `if else` conditions properly scoped. It seems both these conditions are met `else  {    echo '-2';` and `else
  {
  $sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; // Storing source path of the file in a variable
  $targetPath = "upload/".$_FILES['file']['name']; // Target path where file is to be stored
  move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath) ; // Moving Uploaded file
    echo '0';
  }`

Comment: U R right. It prints -2 (file already exists) and then 0 - success. But I deleted the file before I submited it.

Comment: Thanx for your answer, I consider it solved.